# How to center a game in Flash Projector (like AdamAtomic's CAPSULE)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Adam Atomic's game Capsule is a flash projector. If you press escape, the game goes out of fullscreen and just shows windowed. How do I get my (FLIXEL/AS3) game to show up centered like that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not into Flixel, but don't you simply need this?

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = '';
```

stage.align is '' by default.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#align

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#scaleMode

Comment: awesome. If I don't add the stage.align ='' it didn't work, and I Wasn't aware the property existed.

Comment: There's nothing in the docs about it, StageAlign.CENTER_CENTER doesn't exist, but you can check stage.align on start and it's '', and it's effect is centering. Maybe Flixel changes your stage.align ?

Comment: I'm sorry if my reply was confusing, but it works with align='' !